# Specific function keys not working

Tags: brightness, toshiba-satellite, function-keys

My Toshiba C800 laptop (12.04 LTS desktop) has special function keys as follows:

<kbd>fn</kbd> + :

- <kbd>F2</kbd> -> BRIGHTNESS DOWN
- <kbd>F3</kbd> -> BRIGHTNESS UP
- <kbd>F4</kbd> -> DISPLAY SELECT
- <kbd>F5</kbd> -> TOUCH PAD on/off
- <kbd>F6</kbd> -> PREVIOUS
- <kbd>F7</kbd> -> PLAY/PAUSE
- <kbd>F8</kbd> -> NEXT
- <kbd>F9</kbd> -> VOLUME DOWN
- <kbd>F10</kbd> -> VOLUME UP
- <kbd>F11</kbd> -> MUTE
- <kbd>F12</kbd> -> WiFi on/off

<kbd>F6</kbd> to <kbd>F11</kbd> (media player keys) work correctly, but the keys from <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> are not working.

Why would some function keys work, but not others? What can be done to fix this?

Comment: some of these can be set under keyboard shorcuts, have you tried any boot parameters? like acpi_osi=Linux or acpi_osi=Windows

Comment: I had a similar problem, this answered it for me: [Function Keys Don't Work (Brightness & Sound)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the package fnfxd? Supposed to enable access to the function keys in Toshiba laptops, though have not tried this personally. You may also wish to check for [fnfx-client in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fnfx/0.3-14ubuntu1). Have not personally tried as my laptop is pre-built for Ubuntu by a  company that only builds Ubuntu laptops, so the hardware just works. However, still do my own builds and deployment methods.