# Function Keys Do Not work (Brightness & Sound) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: brightness, function-keys

Installed Ubuntu 16.04 on ASUS laptop, everything worked except <kbd>fn</kbd> keys.  Cannot mute/increase/decrease volume (<kbd>f10</kbd>, <kbd>f11</kbd>, <kbd>f12</kbd>) or increase/decrease screen brightness (<kbd>f5</kbd>, <kbd>f6</kbd>).

In troubleshooting I found people have similar issues regardless of machine (ASUS, ACER, Dell) or Ubuntu version, anywhere from 8.0-16.04
 

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you were able to solve it yourself, better post it as an answer :)

Comment: lenovo: https://askubuntu.com/questions/468277/screen-brightness-isnt-taking-effect-on-a-lenovo-z570

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Edit **GRUB** config file to pass a kernel boot parameter

   - Open Terminal
   - type `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - Find this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   - Add `acpi_osi=` immediately following `quiet splash` to give: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`
   - The next line should look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
   - SAVE and CLOSE file
   - In terminal, type `sudo update-grub`
2. Create **.CONF** file

   - Open Terminal
   - type (or copy/paste): `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
   - Enter this in the file line for line:

     ```
     Section "Device"
     Identifier  "card0"
     Driver      "intel"
     Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
     BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
     EndSection
     ```
   - SAVE and CLOSE file
3. Reboot computer

The above steps fixed my problem and I was able to use the function keys to control brightness and volume on my machine. I tried several things and edited the GRUB file several times, updating and rebooting every time. Some threads suggested edited the BIOS, others suggested installing `xbacklight`. It took a while to troubleshoot. If my solution doesn't work for you, here are threads that helped me:

- [This one edits GRUB slightly differently](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/enable-fn-keys-on-your-asus-eeepc-and.html)
- [This is what I used the create the 20-intel.conf file (but the GRUB specifics did not work for me)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363087/13-10-cant-adjust-dell-laptop-backlight/401311#401311)
- [Why does the Kernel Boot Parameter Set ACPI OSI Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do)
- [Linux Kernel Boot Parameters](http://redsymbol.net/linux-kernel-boot-parameters/)

Comment: I would add a link to https://askubuntu.com/questions/28848/what-does-the-kernel-boot-parameter-set-acpi-osi-linux-do or http://redsymbol.net/linux-kernel-boot-parameters/

Comment: The `20-intel.conf` file fixed my issue, but the grub changes caused my splash screen to not show up and broke the trackpad. Reverted that and kept the `.conf` file, and everything is perfect.

Comment: On my laptop (Sony VAIO PCG-4K1M running Lubuntu) just the GRUB part was sufficient to make it work. The brightness changes in small steps, so I needed to press multiple times to see it work.

Comment: This made my system stop loading :D I had to load in recovery mode and undo all things I've done)

Comment: Sorry, I did same but noting worked for me. I am using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: No result in Xubuntu 20.04, Asus X541UJ :(

Comment: This solution has a negative effect on the performance of the graphics card and other things

Answer (score 25):

You might have the <kbd>FnLock</kbd> activated. You might be able to deactivate it by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. [Source](https://www.howtogeek.com/235351/how-to-choose-whether-your-function-keys-are-f1-f12-keys-or-special-keys/)

Comment: Thanks!! You saved my day!

Answer (score 4):

Please check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard?fbclid=IwAR007eH-nVJJ09JoSifVaXW4Zc_aEDI5VL_IUEOYj1XWxvhMpXkVpo-Y-Tw) article. You might need to change the fnmode value in `sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`. For me it worked by changing it from `1` to `0`. I did not need to reboot or anything.

Comment: Worked for me, using Keychron keyboard (MacOS layout)

Comment: Perhaps a wild coincidence, but I *also* had this problem and I am *also* using a Keychron keyboard, but with the Windows layout. Great.

Comment: Keychron keyboard as well. Just so anyone seeing this answer might manage their expectations.

Comment: Works for NuPhy Air 75. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Kelly for your solution! It helped me to localize the problem on my own system (Ubuntu 19.04, Dell XPS 15 7590 <kbd>FN11</kbd>..<kbd>FN12</kbd> not working).

1. Backup **GRUB** config file

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
   ```
2. Edit **GRUB** config file

   - type `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
   - Find this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash"` (it may contain different options based on your specific configuration)
   - Add `acpi_osi=Linux` immediately following `quiet splash` to give: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`
   - The next line may look differently depending on your configuration, but it SHOULD NOT contain `acpi_backlight=vendor`. remove this option if it's present. the resulting line should be for example: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi_osi=! acpi_osi=Linux mem_sleep_default=deep"`
   - SAVE the file
   - `sudo update-grub`
3. Create **.CONF** file

   - Open Terminal
   - type (or copy/paste): `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
   - Enter this in the file line for line:

     ```
     Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
     EndSection
     ```
   - SAVE the file
4. Reboot computer

Answer (score 0):

I know that the questioner got the answer, but since I was involved in this issue and I guess others may have the same problem as me, so I will raise this.

I have another keyboard connected to my laptop and these **fn keys** did not work.

First, test your keyboards physically before executing any commands. If you have a laptop, check the fn keys on its **built-in keyboard**.

It might sound strange but connecting it to a **USB hub** was causing problems for me. Connect the keyboard directly to the laptop or change its port. Your problem may be solved.