# Brightness keys not working ASUS ROGg531

Tags: nvidia, asus, brightness

I am using an ASUS ROG laptop with NVIDIA Graphics. I installed the nvidia x server driver using the driver manager in ubuntu 18.04. My volume keys work but my brightness keys do not.

I tried updating my grub and conf file as detailed in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04) but to no avail.

What can I do to make my brightness keys work or any alternatives that I can employ, such as map the command like `sudo echo 100 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to a shortcut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
sudo apt install brightnessctl
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/brightnessctl
sudo chmod 4775 /usr/bin/brightnessctl
```

Use the following commands:

```bsh
/usr/bin/brightnessctl set 2400- # To Decrease
/usr/bin/brightnessctl set 2400+ # To Increase
```