# Brightness and wifi fn keys not working and laptop not suspend Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, shortcut-keys, suspend, brightness

I have hp pavilion gaming i5 8300h , gtx 1050ti and i'm using Ubuntu 18.04. brightness fn (f5 and f6) and wifi fn (f12) are not working and when i turn of the screen it don't suspend but just give black screen and when i open it again it turns on airplane mode

Comment: Your problem seems similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04). Have you tried the [solutions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04) listed?

Comment: Yes but didn't work ☹️

Comment: What didn't work? The more information we get the more we can help you. Simply saying that you tried and it didn't work, especially for your case, is not very helpful. What changed after you tried the solutions Idias listed? Did you try anything else since?

Comment: Actually nothing changed  i tried the above solution but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

fn keys are bound to keycombination that work with frameworks which are installed by the manufacturing company alongside windows.It doesnt work with Ubuntu

Comment: But sound fn keys works 

Comment: @MarkRefaat some do tends to work , maybe its coded into system frimware , some like rgb controlling keys are coded to framework like asus armoury crate which is not available in Ubuntu