# Function Keys for Trackpad, Keyboard Backlight, and Camera not Working

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, function-keys

I have an Asus Zenbook UX425JA. Came pre-installed with Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 instead.

Most function keys are working (Volume, mute, screen brightness, screen lock keys all work), but some do not, in particular the one for enabling/disabling the trackpad, one for controlling keyboard backlight, and one for enabling/disabling the camera.
Function lock (`Fn+Esc`) does not work either.

I tried the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866437/function-keys-do-not-work-brightness-sound-ubuntu-16-04), but the grub edit made even more function keys nonfunctional, and when I added the config file, I was getting strange lines on my screen (green vertical line on my desktop, horizontal white strips in browser... thought my screen was broken tbh).

I'd super appreciate any help. I'm an absolute noob, this is my first ever experience with Linux, having "declared windependence" 3 hours ago...

EDIT: Following Quasimodo's advice:

> Unfortunately there does not seem to exist a simple route to debug those keyboard problems. You will have to dig more. See if any of `xev`, `evtest`, `showkey`, `acpi_listen` react to the keypresses in question. If yes, you should be fine. Keep following the trail. If you cannot find a solution, edit the question with the information. If none of them detect the keys, you are probably in trouble.

`xev`, `evtest`, `showkey`, and `acpi_listen` all do not react... sounds like I'm in trouble.

I found this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopSpecialKeys
which seems to be relevant to my problem. However, they start out by asking to run `acpi_listen` and say if your key isn't an ACPI key, the guide can't help you, which is exactly my case. What do I do now?

Comment: Unfortunately there does not seem to exist a simple route to debug those keyboard problems. You will have to dig more. See if any of `xev`, `evtest`, `showkey`, `acpi_listen` react to the keypresses in question. If yes, you should be fine. Keep following the trail. If you cannot find a solution, [edit] the question with the information. If none of them detect the keys, you are probably in trouble.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer! I've tried your suggestions and it seems, as you said, I'm in trouble. I've updated the question with the details, I'd love to get your advice on this since I really am stuck and am a total noob :(

Comment: That's a pity! You may then have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/152800/key-is-not-detected-in-xev-neither-showkey-k-in-ubuntu-10-04-in-a-virtualbox-vm and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Extra_keyboard_keys. Also double check it there is no setting in your BIOS related to Fn keys.

Answer (score 1):

Drivers for the function keys on Asus UX425JA were added in Linux 5.8

[Source](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-5.8-x86-Pulls)